# How to create a query that returns only cases on the platform that have more than 10 years since the creation date?

Tags: soql, query

How to create a query that returns only cases on the platform that have more than 10 years since the creation date?

I did this query but it returns data with less than 10 years of creation.

`SELECT ID, CreatedDate  FROM Case WHERE CreatedDate > LAST_N_YEARS:10 order by CreatedDate desc`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want cases with a CreatedDate that is longer than 10 years ago.

[LAST_N_YEARS](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm) is defined as

> Starts 00:00:00 on January 1 of the **previous year** and continues
> through the end of December 31 of the **previous nth year**.

That would be the following range:

`1/1/2020 - 12/31/2011`

By saying `CreatedDate > LAST_N_YEARS:10` you're actually asking for records whose `CreatedDate` is greater (*more recent*) than that range above which would be this year's records.

What you want is `CreatedDate < LAST_N_YEARS:10` which will give you cases that are less (*more in the past*) than 10 years ago.